# Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks, Unexpected Launch Interstitials, Admob

Tags: flutter, admob

I placed the app open ad on the splash screen just as recommended below, but I still get ***Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks - Unexpected Launch Interstitials*** issue.

Here is SplashScreen code example, I load and show my ad in Splash screen.

```
class SplashPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends ConsumerState<SplashPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future.microtask(() async {
      await AppOpenAdManager.shared.loadAd();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 250));
      await ref.read(authStateProvider.notifier).checkAuthStateAndNavigate();
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

And here is my AdmobManagerClass, after loading ad, I show it inside anAdLoaded callback.

```
final class AppOpenAdManager {
  AppOpenAdManager._();
  static final shared = AppOpenAdManager._();

  late final String adUnitId;

  Future<void> initializeAdmob() async {
    if (KDebug.kAdDebugMode) {
      logger.warningPrint("AD DEBUG MODE ACTIVE!");
      return;
    }
    await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
    adUnitId = Platform.isAndroid ? 'SOMEID' : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5575463023';
    await loadAd();
  }

  /// Load an AppOpenAd.
  Future<void> loadAd() async {
    if (KDebug.kAdDebugMode) {
      logger.warningPrint("AD DEBUG MODE ACTIVE!");
      return;
    }

    logger.debugPrint('AppOpenAdManager -> Ad is being loaded...');
    try {
      await AppOpenAd.load(
        adUnitId: adUnitId,
        request: AdRequest(),
        orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait,
        adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) async {
            logger.debugPrint('AppOpenAd -> Add Succeded to load: ${ad}');
            await ad.show();
            // logger.debugPrint(_appOpenAd.toString());
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
            logger.debugPrint('AppOpenAd -> failed to load: ${error}');
          },
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      logger.debugPrint('${e}');
    }
  }
}
```

[image]